# Notify an activity if it is on top

Tags: android, android-activity, service, binding

I am developing an Android app.

I have a service with runs in background periodically, fetches some numbers from a web service.

When the fetching is completed, the results are written into preferences. When the user starts the application, its main activity is displayed. In onResume the numbers are retrieved from preferences, and displayed in the activity. So far, I am good.

What I don't know how to implement is that if the activity is on top when the scheduled fetching completes, the activity should be notified. Meanwhile if the activity is not on top, it should not be started, it is enough to write the numbers into preferences.

How should I implement this? Any idea?

Thanks!

PS: Now that I have typed all this, I have an idea: should the activity bind to this service in onResume and unbind in onPause?

Comment: Seems that what I need is to register a broadcast receiver in onResume, unregister in onPause. The service should sendBroadcast an intent with the fetched numbers as extra data.

This way the activity is not started when the service broadcasts the event, but is notified if currently happens to be active.

Answer (score 0):

You can know which app is on top with this code:

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) ClassName.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningTaskInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningTasks(1000);
                String topApp = procInfos.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().toString();

                if(!topApp .contains("com.yourpackage"){
                   //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT

                }
                else{
                   //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT}
```